# Accumulation points of $X_n$ proof help?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that x $\in \mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point of $x_n$ iff for each m>0, there are infinitely many n $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that |$x_n$ - x| < m.

This questions wants me to prove that n is infinite but wouldn't this follow from definition?

Like since $x_n$ is convergent by definition there exists $n_m$ such that |$x_n$ - x| < m for all $n\geq n_m$ therefore proving n is infinite? I don't think I understand the question

Comment: Are you sure the question states "for all $m>0$"? Generally $\varepsilon$ is the symbol that would be used. Not that it changes the mathematical meaning of the question, it is just weird to see (as $m$ is generally reserved for use e.g. as an index for the sequence).

Comment: The premise "there are infinitely many $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_n-x|<m$ does not imply that $x_n$ converges to $x$. For a counterexample, consider $x_n = (-1)^n$. Then there are infinitely many $n$ such that $|x_n-1|=0$ (namely, all even $n$), but clearly $x_n$ does not converge to $1$.

Comment: @Math1000 The question says epsilon but I didn't know the symbol in latex. Thanks for the counterexample the question looked very similar to the definition in my notes so I just assumed it was the same

Comment: The symbol would be \epsilon for $\epsilon$ or \varepsilon for $\varepsilon$ (I personally prefer the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $x$ is an accumulation point of $x_n$. Then every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $x_n$. Let $m>0$. Then $B(x,m)$, the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $m$, is a neighborhood of $x$ and hence contains a point of $x_n$. Repeat this process for $m/2, m/4, \ldots$ to obtain a subsequence of points contained within $B(x,m/2)$, $B(x,m/4)$, $\ldots$. Then $B(x,m)$ contains all of these points, of which there are infinitely many, as was to be proved.

Assume now that for each $m>0$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $|x_n-x|<m$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$. Then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset U$. Choose $m<\varepsilon$, then there is an $n$ such that $|x_n-x|<m<\varepsilon$ and hence $x_n\in U$. It follows that $x$ is an accumulation point of $x$.